# the rmse that I get from this linear regression algorithm is not logical

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I have written this function for computing linear regression, but I don't know why the rmse that I get is about 170. Can anyone help me find what the problem is.

```py
import sklearn
import numpy as np

def main(args: argparse.Namespace) -> float:
    dataset = sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes()
    dataset['intercept'] = 1
    x = dataset.data
    y = dataset.target
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
    w = np.linalg.inv((np.transpose(x_train))@x_train)@(np.transpose(x_train))@y_train
    y_pred = w@(np.transpose(x_test)
    MSE = sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_pred, y_test)
    rmse = MSE**(1/2)
    rmse = None
    return rmse
```

Answer (score 0):

rmse is set to None in the second-to-last row.

```
    rmse = None
```

Also you could improve your code by importing sklearn libraries as:

```
    from sklearn import datasets
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

And making the corresponding changes to the code beneath:

```
    diabetes_X, diabetes_y = datasets.load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
    intercept = np.ones((diabetes_X.shape[0],1))
    diabetes_X = np.hstack((diabetes_X,intercept))
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(diabetes_X, diabetes_y, test_size=0.2)
    w = np.linalg.inv((np.transpose(x_train))@x_train)@(np.transpose(x_train))@y_train
    y_pred = w@(np.transpose(x_test))
    MSE = sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_pred, y_test)
    rmse = MSE**(1/2)
```

With these changes, the rmse will be between 50-60.